# adapter to correct wrong pins DFN 10

Tags: pins, error

I had some boards made and assembled, but made a mistake with a DFN 10 part, and reversed two pins in the layout.  How do I fix it?

Should I remove the part and create and insert an adapter board to correct the pins?   Are there such things already?   Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How to fix? Respin the board. That's why we do prototypes. Of course, you didn't want to hear that. Else, if possible, cut the tracks and run thin bits of wire.

Comment: It depends on how your board looks like. There is no information what to suggest. I'd cut the traces and swap them with wires, but I don't know if that is possible in your case.

Comment: The trace I need to cut goes to GND under the chip, so no option to cut my way out.   I'm going to remove the part, and create a tiny daughter board, glue it down, and manually wire it back into the circuit.